# Transform SQL Records to Object

Tags: c#, mysql, database, linq

Currently I am developing an application like SharePoint and I am encountering a difficult as followed.

I have a DB table to keep my contents like the following

```
+----+---------------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| ID |  Content_type |  List_ID |  COL_ID |  ITEM_ID |           VALUE          |
+----+---------------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 |  "Column"     |        1 |       0 |          |  "ABC"                   |
|  2 |  "Column"     |        1 |       1 |          |  "DEF"                   |
|  3 |  "Item"       |        1 |       0 |        1 |  "<VALUE OF Column ABC>" |
|  4 |  "Item"       |        1 |       1 |        1 |  "<VALUE OF Column DEF>" |
+----+---------------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
```

and I would like to display these record on the web using linq and C# like the following....

```
  ITEM_ID   |ABC                  |DEF
------------+---------------------+----------------------
    1       |<VALUE OF Column ABC>|<VALUE OF Column DEF>
```

**EDITED:**

My questions are:

1. I would like to use the DB record stated as `Column` in the `content_type` field to be the `DataColumn` of a `DataTable`.
2. I would like to map all records in the DB stated as `ITEM` with the same `Item_ID` as 1 `DataRow` of a `DataTable`. The value field of each DB records will fall onto the column of the `DataTable` based on the `Column ID`.

Comment: Your DB is MySQL ?

Comment: Your question is not a question. It's a statement. Please provide more info about this problem.

Comment: Yes I am using MySQL for the DB

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I had make it by myself....

- First get the records from DB where content_type = "Column" and use
  these records to form a DataTable
- Get all records from DB where content_typ= "Item" and re-group each item to a List where ITEM_id =
- Map the Item.title = column of the DataTable and Items.value = value of the DataTable rows....

  public static DataTable PopulateRec(int list_id, string web_app, string host_auth)
  {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      List Column = Get_Column(list_id, web_app, host_auth);
      for (int i = 0; i < Column.Count(); i++)
      {
          DataColumn datacolumn = new DataColumn();
          datacolumn.ColumnName = Column[i].ToString();
          dt.Columns.Add(datacolumn);
      }
      List Items = Get_Item(list_id, web_app, host_auth);
      if (Items.Count != 0)
      {
          int ItemCount = Convert.ToInt32((from Itms in Items
                                           select Itms.Item_id).Max());
          for (int j = 0; j <= ItemCount; j++)
          {
              dt.Rows.Add();
              List IndvItem = (from Indv in Items
                                       where Indv.Item_id == j
                                       select Indv).ToList();
              foreach (var val in IndvItem)
              {
                  dt.Rows[j][val.title] = val.value;
              }
              IndvItem = null;
          }
          for (int k = 0; k < dt.Rows.Count; k++)
          {
              if (dt.Rows[k][0].ToString() == string.Empty)
              {
                  dt.Rows[k].Delete();
              }
          }
      }
      Column = null;
      Items = null;
      return dt;
  }

  private static List Get_Column(int list_id, string web_app, string host_auth)
  {
      List content_db = new List();
      List columnname = new List();
      Config_DB_Context configdb = new Config_DB_Context("dms_config");
      content_db = (from c in configdb.site_mapping
                    where c.host_auth == host_auth
                    && c.web_app == web_app
                    select c.content_db).ToList();
      for(int i = 0; i < content_db.Count(); i++)
      {
          Content_DB_Context contentdb = new Content_DB_Context(content_db[i]);
          columnname = (from c in contentdb.content
                            where c.content_type == "Column"
                            && c.list_id == list_id
                            select c.title).ToList();
      }
      content_db = null;
      return columnname;
  }

  private static List Get_Item(int list_id, string web_app, string host_auth)
  {
      List content_db = new List();
      List Itm = new List();
      Config_DB_Context configdb = new Config_DB_Context("dms_config");
      content_db = (from c in configdb.site_mapping
                    where c.host_auth == host_auth
                    && c.web_app == web_app
                    select c.content_db).ToList();
      for (int i = 0; i < content_db.Count(); i++)
      {
          Content_DB_Context contentdb = new Content_DB_Context(content_db[i]);
          Itm = (from c in contentdb.content
                 where c.content_type == "Item"
                 && c.list_id == list_id
                 select new MyItem
                 {
                     col_id = (int)c.column_id,
                     list_id = (int)c.list_id,
                     title = c.title,
                     value = c.value,
                     Item_id = (int)c.item_id,
                     hidden = c.hidden
                 }).ToList();
      }
      content_db = null;
      return Itm;
  }